# Dataview filtering vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataview

Wondering if I am doing this filter right with the dataview, it keeps throwing me this error

```
Additional information: Filter expression '80' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.
```

but here is the code

```
Dim table = DataSet1.Tables("network")
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = TextBox1.Text
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Comment: MSDN page on RowFilter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and no, you are not doing it right. You need to set the RowFilter with a string like _"fieldName"+ "comparisonOperator"+ "valueToFilterFor"_, what is the name of the column on which you want to apply your filter value?

Comment: @Steve that's literally no help

Comment: To filter something on a DataVIew you need to specify the column on which the filter should be applied, the operator for the comparison and the value that you want to use for the filtering. It seems that you have given only the value "80". I ask again, what is the name of the column on which you want to apply the filter?

Comment: I mean what is the name of the column in the table "network".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter something on a DataVIew you need to specify the column on which the filter should be applied, the operator for the comparison and the value that you want to use for the filtering. It seems that you have given only the value "80".

For example, assuming the column of interest is named "NumberOfPieces" and you have typed 80 in the textbox

```
Dim table = DataSet1.Tables("network")
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "NumberOfPieces = " & TextBox1.Text
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

This will filter the view with all the rows that have the value (a numeric value) equals to 80 in the column "NumberOfPieces". You could use other operators like Greater/Lesser Than ( >=  <= ) or more complex construct that are well detailed in the MSDN page about the [Expression property of the DataColumn object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This means that you have only one row that matches the condition applied. I am sorry but cannot help more that that without having your data and the query used to retrieve that data